# Define Global variables from File input C++

Tags: c++, file-io, initialization

I have to define a global array in my C++ code the size of which has to be read from a file. I am using the below code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

string inputfile = "input.txt";
ifstream infile(inputfile.c_str());
infile>>N; // N = size of Array
int array[N];

// ------some code here-----

int main(){
int N;
cout << N<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

But if I place the 3 lines

```
string inputfile = "input.txt";
ifstream infile(inputfile.c_str());
infile>>N; // N = size of Array
```

inside the main loop this code works. Unfortunately I cant put it inside any function because I need to initialise a global array from variable N.

I have asked many people and searched different places but I cant seem to be able to figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry.. what loop? Are you on a win32 event dispatching loop or what?

Comment: As a _general_ rule executable code must stay inside a function. That's why your first code doesn't even compile. Declare `int* array` as global and allocate memory when you have value for `N`. Better: you're in C++ then use `std::vector`.

Comment: You can't. Statements need to go in functions. The best you can do is use some kind of code generation tool at compile time.

Comment: I suggest using a vector unless you have some requirements on how memory should be handled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of an array has to be a constant expression, i.e. known at compile-time.

Reading a value from a file is an inherently *dynamic* operation, that happens at run-time.

One option is to use dynamic allocation:

```
int array_size()
{
  int n;
  ifstream infile("input.txt");
  if (infile>>n)
    return n;
  else
    throw std::runtime_error("Cannot read size from file");
}
int* array = new int[array_size()];
```

However it would be better to replace the array with `std::vector<int>` which can be resized dynamically.

Comment: +1 for vector which I also mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 2):

Use a global pointer. Define

```
int* array;
```

in the global space before your main procedure. Then later, in a loop or not, say

```
array = new int[N];
```

to allocate your array. Just remember to also say

```
delete[] array;
```

before you exit your `main` or re-allocate `array`

Answer (score 1):

`int array[N];` - `N` should be know at compile-time.
Instead, use `int array[]=new int[N]; /*some code using array*/ delete[] array;`

```
int *array;

int main(){
    ifstream infile("input.txt");
    unsigned N;
    infile>>N;
    array=new int[N];

    //using array...

    delete[] array; //when no longer needed.
                   //don't use array after this line
                  //unless it's array=new int[] instruction
                 //or you know what you're doing.
}
```

Comment: `int array[];` is not a valid variable definition, you want `int* array;` instead